# Works in the console but not in the .js file

Tags: javascript, console, addeventlistener, keypress

i worked with addEventListner and it did work for the "click" propritie but not with "keypress" one,
so i tried the same code in the console and I had the result I was hoping for,so I got back to my code and refreshed my page and the same problem no respond.

I expected the tracking to be played when I press some keys in my keyboard.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
  makeSound(event.key);
});
function makeSound(key){
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
      tom1.play();
      break;
    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
      tom2.play();
    break;
    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
      tom4.play();
    break;
    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
      tom3.play();
    break;
    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
      snare.play();
    break;
    case "k":
      var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
      crash.play();
    break;
    case "l":
      var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
      kick.play();
    break;
    default:

  }
```

Comment: Do you mean the keypress worked in the browser console? How where you able to test that

Comment: yes i tried it in the browser console, i called the same function and when i tested it and clicked on my keyboard keys it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try "rewinding" the sound before playing it

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', makeSound)

const tom1 = new Audio('./tom1.wav')
const tom2 = new Audio('./tom2.wav')
    
function makeSound(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 's':
      tom1.currentTime = 0;
      tom1.play();
      break;
    case 'd':
      tom2.currentTime = 0;
      tom2.play();
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i did some changing in my code and it worked.